# Making new breakpoints in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide content using bootstraps (v4) .d-none and .d-xl-block classes.

The problem is that these respond to fast. I hoped it would help me display content on my widescreen monitor and hide it on the laptop. But is shows on the laptop as well.

Is there any easy way to add something like an xxl breakpoint to bootstrap?

Comment: Write your own media query targeting whatever dimensions you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Comment: You have to use SASS to add an entirely new breakpoint, or just add a new `.d-xl-block` class in CSS

Comment: I was hoping I would not have to write media queries. Seems there is no escaping.